# Call a class function from inside another class

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Newbie here, trying to get this to work:
I am making an online index for a library. I am using php and mySQL which I am running on an apache server. I have created a class called book which contains information about each book, and a static class called DBFunctions which contains only static functions that I call to connect and interact with the database.
I'm trying to call a function from the DBFunctions class from inside the Book class but I keep getting an error. My function within the book class is:

```
function setTagIDs(){
   this->TagIDs = DbFunctions::getTagIdsForBook($this->BookID);
}
```

the dbFunction creates a select statement connects to the database and returns the result. It works fine on a test page.

But when I call it from within the class I get the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in \Classes\ClassBook.php on line 111

I've looked in quite a few places but I can't figure out what the problem is, any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Steven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply missing a `$` on `this`:

```
  $this->TagIDs = DbFunctions::getTagIdsForBook($this->BookID);
  ^^
```

`unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` indicates a `->` was encountered before it should have been there. So to interpret the error, find the first `->` and look backwards.

Comment: @user985331 Don't. You're a self-proclaimed n00b and you'll get used to how PHP reports parse errors. If you don't have one, get a text editor that supports syntax highlighting.  A missing `$` _might_ become immediately obvious with syntax highlighting, depending on the editor.